# Why I Cannot Access to this function?

Tags: kotlin

I've been past this example of watchface from java to kotlin, but I suddenly notice that I can not access three functions. (I only mention one because the error is the same "unresolved reference")

I do not understand why I can not access them, I have changed the access modifiers I have extended one class to another but I can not access those functions

I will appreciate your valuable comments

class ComplicationConfigActivity : WearableActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

```
private val TAG = "Configuration Activity"

internal val COMPLICATION_CONFIG_REQUEST_CODE = 1001 // internal val COMPLICATION_CONFIG_REQUEST_CODE = 1001


enum class ComplicationLocation {
    LEFT,
    RIGHT,
    TOP,
    BOTTOM
}//---

private var mLeftComplicationId: Int = 0
private var mRightComplicationId: Int = 0
//---
private var mTopComplicationId: Int = 0
private var mBottomComplicationId: Int = 0
//---



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_complication_config)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_complication_config)
    mDefaultAddComplicationDrawable = getDrawable(R.drawable.add_complication)

    mSelectedComplicationId = -1

    mLeftComplicationId = MyWatchFace.getComplicationId(ComplicationLocation.LEFT) // unresolved reference
    mRightComplicationId = MyWatchFace.getComplicationId(ComplicationLocation.RIGHT) // getComplicationId
    mTopComplicationId = MyWatchFace.getComplicationId(ComplicationLocation.TOP)
    mBottomComplicationId = MyWatchFace.getComplicationId(ComplicationLocation.BOTTOM)
```

class MyWatchFace : CanvasWatchFaceService() {

```
private val TAG = "ComplicationConfigActivity"
// TODO: Step 2, intro 1
private val LEFT_COMPLICATION_ID = 0
private val RIGHT_COMPLICATION_ID = 1
private val TOP_COMPLICATION_ID = 2
private val BOTTOM_COMPLICATION_ID = 3

private val COMPLICATION_IDS =
    intArrayOf(LEFT_COMPLICATION_ID, RIGHT_COMPLICATION_ID, TOP_COMPLICATION_ID, BOTTOM_COMPLICATION_ID)

// Left and right dial supported types.
private val COMPLICATION_SUPPORTED_TYPES = arrayOf(
    intArrayOf(
        ComplicationData.TYPE_RANGED_VALUE, ComplicationData.TYPE_ICON, ComplicationData.TYPE_SHORT_TEXT,
        //ComplicationData.IMAGE_STYLE_PHOTO,//
        ComplicationData.TYPE_SMALL_IMAGE
    ), intArrayOf(
        ComplicationData.TYPE_RANGED_VALUE, ComplicationData.TYPE_ICON, ComplicationData.TYPE_SHORT_TEXT,
        //ComplicationData.IMAGE_STYLE_PHOTO,//
        ComplicationData.TYPE_SMALL_IMAGE
    ), intArrayOf(
        ComplicationData.TYPE_RANGED_VALUE, ComplicationData.TYPE_ICON, ComplicationData.TYPE_SHORT_TEXT,
        //ComplicationData.IMAGE_STYLE_PHOTO,//
        ComplicationData.TYPE_SMALL_IMAGE
    ), intArrayOf(
        ComplicationData.TYPE_RANGED_VALUE, ComplicationData.TYPE_ICON, ComplicationData.TYPE_SHORT_TEXT,
        //ComplicationData.IMAGE_STYLE_PHOTO, //
        ComplicationData.TYPE_SMALL_IMAGE
    )
)

// Used by {@link ComplicationConfigActivity} to retrieve id for complication locations and
// to check if complication location is supported.
// TODO: Step 3, expose complication information, part 1
//---
internal fun getComplicationId( // CAN´T ACCESS THIS FUNCTION
    complicationLocation: ComplicationLocation
): Int {
    when (complicationLocation) {
        LEFT -> return LEFT_COMPLICATION_ID
        RIGHT -> return RIGHT_COMPLICATION_ID
        TOP -> return TOP_COMPLICATION_ID
        BOTTOM -> return BOTTOM_COMPLICATION_ID
        else -> return -1
    }
}
//----
// Used by {@link ComplicationConfigActivity} to retrieve all complication ids.
// TODO: Step 3, expose complication information, part 2
//---
internal fun getComplicationIds(): IntArray { // CAN´T ACCESS THIS FUNCTION

    return COMPLICATION_IDS
}
//---

// Used by {@link ComplicationConfigActivity} to retrieve complication types supported by
// location.
// TODO: Step 3, expose complication information, part 3
//---
internal fun getSupportedComplicationTypes( // CAN´T ACCESS THIS FUNCTION
    complicationLocation: ComplicationLocation
): IntArray {
    when (complicationLocation) {
        LEFT -> return COMPLICATION_SUPPORTED_TYPES[0]
        RIGHT -> return COMPLICATION_SUPPORTED_TYPES[1]
        TOP -> return COMPLICATION_SUPPORTED_TYPES[2]
        BOTTOM -> return COMPLICATION_SUPPORTED_TYPES[3]
        else -> return intArrayOf()
    }
}
//---

/*
 * Update rate in milliseconds for interactive mode. We update once a second to advance the
 * second hand.
 */
private val INTERACTIVE_UPDATE_RATE_MS = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1)


override fun onCreateEngine(): Engine {
    return Engine()
}

private class EngineHandler(reference: Engine) : Handler() { // 
    private val mWeakReference: WeakReference<Engine> = WeakReference(reference)

    override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
        val engine = mWeakReference.get()
        if (engine != null) {
            when (msg.what) {
                MSG_UPDATE_TIME -> engine.handleUpdateTimeMessage()
            }
        }
    }
}

inner class Engine : CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine() {}
```

Comment: The problem is here, i got an Unresolved reference


 mLeftComplicationId = MyWatchFace.getComplicartionId(ComplicationLocation.LEFT)

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `getComplicationId` like a *static* method, but it's an *Instance* method instead. 
To solve, put that method (and the variables it uses) inside a [Companion Object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects) :

```
class MyWatchFace : CanvasWatchFaceService() {
    companion object{
        private val LEFT_COMPLICATION_ID = 0
        private val RIGHT_COMPLICATION_ID = 1
        private val TOP_COMPLICATION_ID = 2
        private val BOTTOM_COMPLICATION_ID = 3

        internal fun getComplicationId(complicationLocation: ComplicationLocation): Int {
            when (complicationLocation) {
                ComplicationLocation.LEFT -> return LEFT_COMPLICATION_ID
                ComplicationLocation.RIGHT -> return RIGHT_COMPLICATION_ID
                ComplicationLocation.TOP -> return TOP_COMPLICATION_ID
                ComplicationLocation.BOTTOM -> return BOTTOM_COMPLICATION_ID
                else -> return -1
            }
        }
    }
}
```